# Using GSP views in plain Spring MVC without Grails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, groovy, gsp

I would like to use GSP views instead of JSP/JSTL views in a plain old Spring MVC application. I have added a groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet to web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GroovyTemplate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>template.engine</param-name>
            <param-value>groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GroovyTemplate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And setup a Spring InternalResourceViewResolver to load the GPS files. Upto this point it all works fine, but to expose the values in the Model to the template I had to do some tricks (subclassing TemplateServlet and adding them to the ServletBinding).

Now my next obstacle is that JSTL by default escapes XML when using the c:out tag and Grails has the notion of codecs to automatically escape values used in a GSP. The template method described above does not escape by default, which requires the developers to be very careful to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.

Is there another (better) way to use GSP including automatic escaping in a plain Spring MVC application without using Grails?

Comment: I'm working on an identical task. I'd like to use GSP templates instead of JSP/JSTL. What dependencies should I add to my gradle build file?

Answer (score 1):

Today GSP for Spring Boot was just released.  This provides the ability to use GSP instead of JSP in a regular Spring web application.  You can see an example here: https://github.com/grails/grails-boot/blob/master/sample-apps/gsp/script/templates/index.gsp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `TemplateServlet`, you could have also used a `GroovyPagesServlet` for that purpose (I haven't tested that, just looked at Grails' *web.xml* and the class' code).
The latter requires a Spring bean to be setup, named `groovyPagesTemplateEngine`, and typed `GroovyPagesTemplateEngine` (`GStringTemplateEngine` in this case).

Configuring the view layer with an `InternalResourceViewResolver` is correct. You'll have assigned a `GroovyPageView`.

GSPs, by default, are *not* configured to perform HTML output escaping. To configure that, change `grails.views.default.codec` from `none` to `html` in *Config.groovy*. See [this article](http://alwaysthecritic.typepad.com/atc/2010/06/grails-gsp-html-escaping-confusion.html) for more information.

Comment: I picked TemplateServlet because that is part of Groovy itself, the GroovyPagesServlet seems like a part of Grails? The same goes for GroovyPageView, it requires setting up Grails filters. One of my requirements is to not include Grails, so I'm looking for the most lean solution for including just GSP support

Comment: Next time, please phrase your requirements in the original question (and not in a later comment). This will save us lots of efforts. - Thanks. - After all, you've found *your* solution (which appears to work fine), except of being mistaken on your most central point of GSP HTML escaping. - This has been addressed in my answer as well. - Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry. - In your original question, you've mentioned (in the question title) "without Grails", and I had not recognized that. - However, your remaining question on GSP HTML escaping should now have been solved.

Comment: Well, sorry you missed the title. But the grails.views.default.codec setting you mention is also Grails specific, as far as I can tell from looking at the source of GStringTemplateEngine. So to clarify: I am looking for a way to use GSP with automatic escaping, as in the original question: "Is there another (better) way to use GSP including automatic escaping in a plain Spring MVC application?" (and thus as mentioned in the title: without Grails)

Comment: `<%@page defaultCodec="html" %>`

Comment: Could anybody give an example of a working web.xml file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have extracted GSP from Grails, customized it for Spring MVC applications and improved configuration support. Please see our tool [Rabbtor](http://knowledgebase.rabbytes.com/display/rabbtordoc/GSP+%28+Groovy+Server+Pages+%29+Template+Engine). We don't provide it open source, but usage is free of charge and we have been using it in our own applications. GSP for Spring Boot depends on Spring boot, it is not maintained and some tag libraries depend on Grails. We removed these dependencies, created our own custom tag libraries which better suit Spring MVC apps.Most tag libraries are supported and have similar implemantations to Spring JSP tags.A data-bound form tag library is provided and also you can register your tag libs or packages.