# Using GSP instead of JSP for Spring MVC applications

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web, gsp

I would like to create a Spring MVC web application but would like to use GSP pages for the views. I need to know what dependencies I should use and how to configure the application (on web.xml and servlet-context.xml).

Thanks,

Comment: You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289665/using-gsp-views-in-plain-spring-mvc-without-grails

Comment: @erhun, the answers require using Grails jars not a standalone GSP solution. One of the given answers points out to use Spring Boot not MVC alone.

Comment: I think,you are asking from the prospect of Eclipse environment as in Eclipse one has to map each of the **action** to the file where we have coded it,But it depends on Environment.You have to use Groovy Framework as @The_Cute_Hedgehog said grails is not stand alone solution.IntelijIdea Environment is best for it you don't need to create WEB.XML because of url pattern /controler/view.gsp